# Inline SVG embedded CSS interpreted at page-level?

Tags: css, svg

I've run across the issue that given an HTML page with several SVG files embedded inline in the page, the CSS in the SVG is interpreted at page-level, not inside the SVG object itself. For example:

```
<body>
<svg id="svg-one" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
  <style type="text/css">rect { fill:green; }</style>
  <rect x="5" y="5" height="100" width="100" />
</svg>
<svg id="svg-two" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
  <style type="text/css">rect { fill:red; }</style>
  <rect x="5" y="5" height="100" width="100" />
</svg>
</body>
```

Both rectangles end up red; the CSS in the second overrides the CSS in the first.

My goal is for each SVG file to be able to be downloaded on its own and have its own styles inside it to display properly, independent of the others and to be displayed with the others. Given that the `id` of the `<svg>` element may change, the best option I thought of is to wrap the whole SVG contents in a group and modify the CSS appropriately:

```
<body>
<svg id="svg-one" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
  <style type="text/css">#ultimate-green-ness rect { fill:green; }</style>
  <g id="ultimate-green-ness"><rect x="5" y="5" height="100" width="100" /></g>
</svg>
<svg id="svg-two" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
  <style type="text/css">#ultimate-red-ness rect { fill:red; }</style>
  <g id="ultimate-red-ness"><rect x="5" y="5" height="100" width="100" /></g>
</svg>
</body>
```

This would allow the downloaded version of the SVG to exactly match the online embedded one, with the downside of there being an group added to every SVG.

Is there a better way to isolate the embedded CSS of inline SVGs?

Comment: You could add the scoped attribute to the style element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) Firefox and Webkit support that.

Comment: @RobertLongson good note! That will be useful when more widely-supported!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options here.  Since you are already uniquely identifying each SVG element, you can make your embedded rules more specific, so that in the whole-page context, they only apply to the SVG they were packaged with, i.e.

```
svg#svg-one #ultimate-green-ness { properties here}
```

you can also just set the fill (or just about anything else) via normal svg attributes, which would take your styling out of the CSS namespace and prevent conflicts, the styling would obviously then be on a per-element level

```
<svg><rect fill="#ffffff" etc... />
```

note that you can still override these styles with external style sheets or JS code.  lastly, to continue the thought you were suggesting above, you can just give ID's to your rects, no need for a group there...

hope that helps.

EDIT:  couple more options... use a `<def>` to contain the styles, then apply that Def to the element, or simply put a "style" attribute in the svg element, although this doesn't scale well in your case.

Lastly, to explain your situation, the stacking of the style tags works the same way it would in HTML, that is , if you had several different  blocks in your HTML (or SVG) the browser simply concats them all into one effective stylesheet and cascades according to the CSS spec.  No getting around that.

the spec is helpful here...
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS